# EXP(x) approximation in old 1980's computer ROM

Tags: approximation

**The presentation :**

Old 1980’s ROM (Apple 2e, Commodore 64, ...) uses a Taylor’s series-like to evaluate the exponential function EXP(x) :

```
EXP(x) = 1 + x + 1/2! x^2 + ... + 1/7! x^7
```

x is in [-1, 1], thanks to a preliminary work.
Another preliminary work is to multiply x by a correction factor 1/ln(2) (better for the algorithm I suppose).
So the series must take into account this factor and modify the coefficients :

```
EXP(x) = 1 + ln(2) x + ln(2)^2 1/2! x^2 + ... + ln(2)^7 1/7! x^7
EXP(x) = a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + ... a7 x^7

a0 = 1.000000000
a1 = 0.693147181 ln(2)
a2 = 0.240226507
a3 = 0.055504109
a4 = 0.009618129
a5 = 0.001333356
a6 = 0.000154035
a7 = 0.000015253
```

To reduce the Taylor error, especially near -1 and 1, the old 1980’s algorithm modify the coefficients with the Chebyshev polynomials approximation.
As the comment says :

```
“TCHEBYSHEV MODIFIED TAYLOR SERIES COEFFICIENTS FOR E**X”

b0 = 1.000000000
b1 = 0.693147186
b2 = 0.240226385
b3 = 0.055505127
b4 = 0.009614017
b5 = 0.001342263
b6 = 0.000143523
b7 = 0.000021499

(see https://github.com/wsoltys/multicomp/blob/master/ROMS/6809/basic.asm line 3852)
```

**Now, the problem :**

**Where these Chebyshev values come from ?**

I did a lot of calculations to retreive these values.
I used the normal method : compute the Chebyshev coefficients for EXP(x) up to 8 terms, then replace the Ti(x) by its x polynomial.
Or by the economization method : compute Taylor EXP(x) up to x^9, and remove a9*T9(x)/2^8 and a8*T8(x)/2^7 (normally equivalent to the first method).
No chance !

The computed Chebyshev coefficients I obtain, in accordance with the literature, are :

```
c0 = 0.999999801   delta   b0 - c0 =  0.000000199
c1 = 0.693147113           b1 - c1 =  0.000000073
c2 = 0.240229556           b2 - c2 = -0.000003171
c3 = 0.055504542           b3 - c3 =  0.000000585
c4 = 0.009610825           b4 - c4 =  0.000003192
c5 = 0.001332605           b5 - c5 =  0.000009658
c6 = 0.000159622           b6 - c6 = -0.000016099
c7 = 0.000015734           b7 - c7 =  0.000005765
```

Have you an idea ?
Is the ROM coefficients really Chebyshev coefficients ?
Is this another approximation method ?
Am I wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

BR,

see https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/1980s-rom-which-expn-algorithm-used in retrocomputing forum

Comment: I consider it impossible to reverse engineer how coefficients were computed. Forcing leading coefficient to 1 for computing $\exp(x)$ is common, compare my work using minimax approximation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381117/which-exponentiation-algorithms-do-cpu-programming-languages-use/29382053#29382053). One candidate is [Chebyshev economization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145678/help-with-chebyshev-economization-of-expx), also referred to as telescoping. Use of the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm) is another likely candidate.

Comment: Those coefficients $b_n$ seem to be intended to approximate $2^x$ on the interval $[0, 1]$ (not on $[-1,1]$) and give the correct value at both ends. It doesn’t seem to minimize the maximum error. Just good enough to get $9$ significant digits.

Comment: A quick application of the Remez algorithm to $2^{x}-1$ on $[0,1]$, minimizing absolute error, yields this set of coefficients (quite close to what you see in the code): $0.693147200, 0.240226190, 0.055506134, 0.009611454, 0.001345703, 0.000141190, 0.000022130$

Comment: $2^{x}-1$ on $[0,1]$, minimizing relative error: $0.693147180, 0.240226488, 0.055504414, 0.009616270, 0.001338690, 0.000146290, 0.000020667$

Comment: The coefficients do not appear to be from the literature. The closest I could find is an approximation to $2^{x}$ on [$0,1]$ on page 41 of Lyusternik, et.al, "Handbook for Computing Elementary Functions" (1965), and an approximation to $2^{x}-1$ on $[0,1]$, approximation EXPBC 1303, in Hart, et. al., "Computer Approximations" (1978)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306550/expx-approximation-in-old-1980s-computer-rom

Comment: The earliest appearance of these coefficients seems to be in the [VIC-20](https://www.mdawson.net/vic20chrome/vic20/docs/kernel_disassembly.txt) which was introduced around 1980. The BASIC for the VIC-20 appears to have been [licensed from Microsoft](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=43), where » Bill Gates wrote “the runtime stuff" [...] and “the math package” «. The people at [Retrocomputing Stackexchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) might know more (but please don't cross-post, it's frowned upon on Stack Exchange), or try inquiring with Mr. Gates.

Comment: And if you do feel compelled to cross-post, then you must leave links to each post at each post.

Comment: Sorry for the crossposted; @njuffa : thx a lot, I will look at this new way; to All other : thx

Comment: @njuffa Monte Davidoff wrote the floating point bits, not Gates

Comment: @srcuss I have no personal knowledge of these matters, I was merely quoting from the blog post I linked, and marked the statement explicitly as a quote by enclosing it in » « . But looking at it again now it appears I misread  (and therefore misquoted) that section, so thank you for jumping in with a correction.